# qgis2web (leaflet) - toggle checkboxes in 'layers list' with javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using qgis2web to create leaflet-maps for my website.

I'm trying to find a way to toggle layers on/off by clicking on links or buttons on my webpage (as opposed to  clicking on the checkboxes in the 'layers list')

However, the checkboxes that qgis2web produces in the 'layers list', do not have unique id's (or classnames) that I could use in some "onclick" event...

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Thanks!